# R error - cannot find function in installed package

Tags: r, package

I am trying to run a oneway whelch Anova in R using the package `userfriendlyscience`.  Below are my steps:

1. install the package using the following command

```r
install.packages("userfriendlyscience")
```

2. direct R to the package library using `library(userfriendlyscience)`.
3. run the oneway test using the command:

```r
one.way <- oneway(data$group, y = data$Volume, posthoc = 'games-howell')
```

However, I get the following errors:

1. When I direct R to the package:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘userfriendlyscience’ in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘psych’ In addition: Warning
> message: package ‘userfriendlyscience’ was built under R version 3.5.3

2. when I run the oneway test:

> Error in oneway(data$group, y = data$Volume, posthoc = "games-howell")
> :    could not find function "oneway"

I am using R version 3.5.2 - could this be the problem? and if so is there a work around or should I download a newer version of R?

Thanks

Comment: *'there is no package called ‘psych’'* - the `psych` package didn't install properly.

Comment: I tried to install psych separately install.packages("psych") and then tried to install userfriendlyscience again with all its dependencies and neither seemed to work install.packages("userfriendlyscience", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)

Comment: That package depends on the `pysch` package and the current version of `psych` depends on `mnormt` which requires at least R 4.0.0 to install. You might get it working by installing older versions of the packages but probably better to update to a more recent version of R.

Comment: Thankyou. I have upgraded by R version and now have it functioning perfectly.